# Смена иконки при авторизации

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

Изучаю Node, express, mongodb, ejs. Сделал регистрацию и авторизацию. При авторизации если логин и пароль правильный редиректит на главную. Как сделать так, чтоб если авторизация прошла, то иконка на главной страницы менялась на другую иконку с показом другой страницы?
Ниже приведу код, если необходимо что то еще обязательно предоставлю. Спасибо за помощь заранее!
Авторизация:

```
async authorization (req, res){
        try {
            const {username, password} = req.body
            const user = await User.findOne({username})
            if (!user) {
                return res.status(400).send(`Пользователь ${username} не найден!`)
            }
            const validPass = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)
            if(!validPass) {
                return res.status(400).send("Введен неправильный пароль")
            }
            const token = generateAccessToken(user._id, user.username, user.roles)
            console.log({token});
            res.redirect("/")
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.status(400).json("Authorization failed")
        }
```

То где надо поменять иконку с другим путем(к примеру на страницу профиля.)

```
<a href="/auth/authorization"><img src="../pages/img/account.png" alt="" class="head__log-img"></a>
```